# filter more than one value in dropdown with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

I'm doing something that needs to make sure the drop-down value cannot be repeated among the few drop-down.
Which means once the value has selected shouldn't appear again inside the rest drop down
Now I face the problem with when I click the first drop down, the value in the second drop down won't apper(this is what I want), it looks nice and works well. But when I select the second dropdown, the third drop down will show the value what I have been selected in its drop-down(This is not what I want).

```js
$('#ext1').on('change', function () {
 if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
  $(this).data('options', $('#ext2 option').clone());
 }
 var val = $(this).val();
 var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value!=\"' + val + '\"]');
 $('#ext2').html(options);
 $('#ext2').val('0');
});

$('#ext2').on('change', function () {
 if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
  $(this).data('options', $('#ext3 option').clone());
 }
 var val = $(this).val();
 var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value!=\"' + val + '\"]');
 $('#ext3').html(options);
 $('#ext3').val('0');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="dext1">
 <label> Extra Vas 1:</label>
 <select name="ext1" id="ext1" ng-model="FormData.Phases">
  <option name="vas" selected value="0"> -- NO EXTRA VAS -- </option>
  <option name="vas" value="1"> VAS 1 </option>
  <option name="vas" value="2"> VAS 2 </option>
  <option name="vas" value="3"> VAS 3 </option>
 </select>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="dext1">
 <label> Extra Vas 2:</label>
 <select name="ext2" id="ext2" ng-model="FormData.Phases">
  <option name="vas2" selected value="0"> -- NO EXTRA VAS -- </option>
  <option name="vas2" value="1"> VAS 1 </option>
  <option name="vas2" value="2"> VAS 2 </option>
  <option name="vas2" value="3"> VAS 3 </option>
 </select>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="dext1">
 <label> Extra Vas 3:</label>
 <select name="ext3" id="ext3" ng-model="FormData.Phases">
  <option name="vas3" selected value="0"> -- NO EXTRA VAS -- </option>
  <option name="vas3" value="1"> VAS 1 </option>
  <option name="vas3" value="2"> VAS 2 </option>
  <option name="vas3" value="3"> VAS 3 </option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This is because on the `ext2` dropdown's `change` event, you are only asking the application to check for values selected by `ext2` you need to check all dropdowns before you get to `ext3`

Comment: ya, that why I ask here. Because I dunno how to select the value in ext1 and make it filter to ext3 drop down.Sorry if can't understand my English.

Comment: So what you can do is rather than use the id (as selector) give the dropdowns a class. Then in the change function loop through all the dropdowns with a simple `$.each` and check if the value has been selected or not.

Comment: That is a way too, thank you for the suggestion. Maybe will use in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the line under `$('#ext2').on('change', function ()`

from:

```
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value!=\"' + val + '\"]');
```

to:

```
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value!=\"' + val + '\"]').filter('[value!=\"' + $('#ext1').val() + '\"]');
```

I have include multiple filters to filter out selected value from 1st select box.

```js
$('#ext1').on('change', function () {
 if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
  $(this).data('options', $('#ext2 option').clone());
 }
 var val = $(this).val();
 var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value!=\"' + val + '\"]');
 $('#ext2').html(options);
 $('#ext2').val('0');
});

$('#ext2').on('change', function () {
 if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
  $(this).data('options', $('#ext3 option').clone());
 }
 var val = $(this).val();
 var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value!=\"' + val + '\"]').filter('[value!=\"' + $('#ext1').val() + '\"]');
 $('#ext3').html(options);
 $('#ext3').val('0');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="dext1">
 <label> Extra Vas 1:</label>
 <select name="ext1" id="ext1" ng-model="FormData.Phases">
  <option name="vas" selected value="0"> -- NO EXTRA VAS -- </option>
  <option name="vas" value="1"> VAS 1 </option>
  <option name="vas" value="2"> VAS 2 </option>
  <option name="vas" value="3"> VAS 3 </option>
 </select>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="dext1">
 <label> Extra Vas 2:</label>
 <select name="ext2" id="ext2" ng-model="FormData.Phases">
  <option name="vas2" selected value="0"> -- NO EXTRA VAS -- </option>
  <option name="vas2" value="1"> VAS 1 </option>
  <option name="vas2" value="2"> VAS 2 </option>
  <option name="vas2" value="3"> VAS 3 </option>
 </select>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="dext1">
 <label> Extra Vas 3:</label>
 <select name="ext3" id="ext3" ng-model="FormData.Phases">
  <option name="vas3" selected value="0"> -- NO EXTRA VAS -- </option>
  <option name="vas3" value="1"> VAS 1 </option>
  <option name="vas3" value="2"> VAS 2 </option>
  <option name="vas3" value="3"> VAS 3 </option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank bro, now I onlly know that can filter two value in the same line. Learn a lot today :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the disabled state of the options if you want to increase the count of selectboxes. Here's a modified version of yours:

```js
$("select[name^='ext']").on("change", function() {
  var selectedValues = [];
  $("select[name^='ext']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() !== "0") selectedValues.push($(this).val());
  });
  $("select[name^='ext'] option:not(:selected)").each(function() {
    if (selectedValues.indexOf($(this).attr("value")) >= 0) {
      $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
      $(this).attr("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dext1">
  <label> Extra Vas 1:</label>
  <select name="ext1" id="ext1" ng-model="FormData.Phases">
    <option name="vas"  selected value="0"> -- NO EXTRA VAS -- </option>
   <option name="vas"   value="1">  VAS 1 </option>
   <option name="vas"   value="2">  VAS 2 </option>
   <option name="vas"   value="3">  VAS 3 </option>
  </select>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="dext2">
  <label> Extra Vas 2:</label>
  <select name="ext2" id="ext2" ng-model="FormData.Phases">
    <option name="vas2"  selected value="0"> -- NO EXTRA VAS -- </option>
  <option name="vas2"   value="1">  VAS 1 </option>
  <option name="vas2"   value="2">  VAS 2 </option>
  <option name="vas2"   value="3">  VAS 3 </option>
  </select>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="dext3">
  <label> Extra Vas 3:</label>
  <select name="ext3" id="ext3" ng-model="FormData.Phases">
    <option name="vas3"  selected value="0"> -- NO EXTRA VAS -- </option>
  <option name="vas3"   value="1">  VAS 1 </option>
  <option name="vas3"   value="2">  VAS 2 </option>
  <option name="vas3"   value="3">  VAS 3 </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I have some question want to ask, if you know please tell me.because I learn jquery less than 6 months , still a newbie.May I know what is the advantage of this `disabled status'?  Because last time I have tried this when playing with the code, and I noticed that this will still show the value and user can't select those value showed, so why not I just hide it or totally don't show it at the first of the time.

Comment: When user selects another date from another dropdown, you won't need to re-add the deleted option again to all other selectboxes. You only will change it's disabled status. And UI/UX-wise, this will tell the users that these options are disabled because of something, and the user will understand that a value shouldn't be selected more than once and prevents confusion. Read this answer: https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/5764/56638